# Select-unselect tree structure in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement a scenario where I have a tree structure and height of the tree will be of 2. Each of the element will have a checkbox and once a node is selected it's children nodes should also be selected. I can easily do this with jquery but I am not able to do it in angular.js. Here is the demo fiddle that of course is not working.

```
<div ng-app="sampleapp" ng-controller="samplecontoller">
  <span ng-repeat="set in countrySet">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master" ng-change="isSelectAll()"> 
    <label>{{ set.name }}</label>
    <br>
    <span ng-repeat="label in labelList">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="label.selected" ng-change="isLabelChecked()">
      <label>{{ label.name }}</label>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alok15ee/Cp73s/4447/

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes by adding `set.` in front of the labelList HTML:

Then copy the $scope.labelList into each set with `angular.forEach` and `angular.copy` JS:

```
angular.forEach($scope.countrySet, function(set){
     set.labelList =angular.copy($scope.labelList);
}));
```